# Longest chain that can be arranged

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I found this problem somewhere in a contest and haven't been able to come up with a solution yet.

> I have the positive integers. I have to find longest subset that among
>   each two neighbour elements one divides another.

What I'm doing is: I'm creating the graph.Then I'm connecting nodes in which numbers divides each others. After that I'm using `DFS` (one node can be connected with two nodes).

But not all test cases are true in system. Do I have to sort the array before using `DFS`? Maybe there is special (Dynamic) algorithm?

Failing test cases:

```
N = 5
1 1 3 7 13
```

My code gives the output `4`. But if I `arrange` this array like this:

```
3 1 7 1 13
```

The output is 5 and it's the true answer.

I also used recursive method. But I need something faster.

Comment: `But not all test cases are true` Please specify failing test case.

Comment: The size of the problem suggests that an algorithm of O(2^n) scale is acceptable, probably multiplying n or n^2. Probably dynamic programming with a bitset dimension and the other dimension is the latest added element.

Comment: @nhahtdh Can you give me the link where i can read about that, please?

Comment: If I have the array `1, 2, 3` I can `arrange` it and have better solution.

Comment: @nhahtdh Please give me more information about that method.

Comment: To explain the title: the relation "a | b" meaning "a divides b" defines a *partial order* on the set (also called a poset). A subset in which all elements are mutually comparable (ie. the order is total) is called a chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is longest path, slightly disguised. We can solve this problem as longest path by preparing a graph where two vertices are adjacent if and only if they satisfy a divisibility relation. See below the horizontal rule for a pointer to the intended answer.

The reduction is (roughly), given an undirected graph in which we would like to find the longest simple path, assign each vertex a distinct prime number. Emit these prime numbers, together with, for each edge, the semiprime that is the product of its endpoints. (We also need two more prime numbers and their 2|V| products with the vertex primes to preserve the objective additively.)

For example, if we have a graph

```
*---*
|  /|
| / |
|/  |
*---*,
```

then we can label

```
2---3
|  /|
| / |
|/  |
5---7,
```

and then the input is

```
2, 3, 5, 7,  # vertices
2*3, 2*5, 3*5, 3*7, 5*7,  # edges
11*2, 11*3, 11*5, 11*7,  # sentinels at one end
2*13, 3*13, 5*13, 7*13,  # sentinels at the other end
```

and (e.g.) the longest path `2, 3, 5, 7` corresponds to the longest sequence `11*2, 2, 2*3, 3, 3*5, 5, 5*7, 7, 7*13` (and three other variants involving reversal and swapping `11` and `13`).

---

Longest path is NP-hard, so  nhahtdh's comment about an O(2^n poly(n))-time dynamic program is right on the money -- see this question and the accepted answer: [Longest path in unweighted undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944340/longest-path-in-unweighted-undirected-graph).

Comment: I don't understand `assign each vertex a distinct prime number.` I'm not really good in English. So, please can you give some example of the graph for the array `1,1,3,5,7`.

Comment: @James Mostly this answer is just supporting my equivalence claim; you want to make the divisibility graph and then use the linked algorithm to solve longest path.

Comment: I get `Time Limit`. My friend who solved the problem said that we have to use dynamic programming  with bit masks.

Comment: @James That's what the linked answer does.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've read about the bit masks and dynamic programming.

Answer (score 3):

You forget to reinit some variables: `used` and `kol`.
Moreover DFS doesn't restore `used[i]` at end for next calls.

Try to avoid global variables, it make the code less clear.
Try also to reduce the scope of variable.

Code may look at something like:

```
void DFS(int (&used)[20], const int (&m)[20][20], int c, int& maxn, int k, int v) {
    used[v] = 1;
    k += 1;
    if(k > maxn)
        maxn = k;
    for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
        if(!used[i] && m[v][i] == 1) {
            DFS(used, m, c, maxn, k, i);
        }
    }
    used[v] = 0;
}
```

and in main:

```
int m[20][20];
memset(m, 0, sizeof(m));

for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < c; ++j) {
        if( (a[i] % a[j] == 0) || (a[j] % a[i] == 0) ) {
            m[i][j] = m[j][i] = 1; // Creating 2D array
        }
    }
}

int maxn = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
    int used[20];
    int k = 0;
    memset(used, 0, sizeof(used));
    DFS(used, m, c, maxn, k, i);
}
std::cout << maxn << std::endl;
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/GAxBWo)

Code may be simplified even more (use `vector`, ...)